# Pass acf fields to Leaflet JS

Tags: php, wordpress, leaflet, advanced-custom-fields

I found this example on the internet that comes pretty close to what I want to do.
I have some ACF fields with the latitude and longitude of some markers, I am trying to show all the markers of the custom post type place in the same map.
But I only get 1, what am I doing wrong?

I think is something related with the marker div

```html
<?php /* Template Name: Demo Page Template */ get_header(); ?>
<h1 class="main-title"><?= post_type_archive_title(); ?></h1>

<section class="list-cases">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row position-relative">
      <?php
        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'lugar',
          'posts_per_page' => 10,
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
      <?php $counter = 1; ?>
      <?php while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ?>
      <div class="item-case-<?= $counter ?> col-md-12" data-hover="<?= $counter ?>" data-aos="fade-up"
        data-aos-duration="2000">
        <div class="case-container">
          <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>
          <p><?php the_field('subtitle') ?></p>
          <p><?php the_field('address') ?></p>
          <p><strong>Latitud:</strong> <?php the_field('lat') ?></p>
          <p><strong>Longitud:</strong> <?php the_field('lon') ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php $counter++; ?>
      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<style>
  #map,
  #acf-map {
    height: 500px;
  }
</style>
<div id="map" style="width: 600px;">


</div>
<div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo the_field('lat') ?>" data-lng="<?php the_field('lon'); ?>"
  data-title="<?php the_field('subtitle')  ?>" data-url="<?php echo 'link'; ?>"
  data-category="<?php echo 'category'; ?>"></div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var map = L.map('map').setView([39.8410802, -0.1191397], 8);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 18,
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1,
      accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamFtYWxkb2xzIiwiYSI6ImNrYmF2bGowOTBycGEyeG84b2F2NGlsYWkifQ.9rqymFnsW79aCkAFGCo0XQ'
    }).addTo(map);


    var marker = [];
    $.each($('.marker'), function () {
      var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat');
      var lng = $(this).attr('data-lng');
      var name = $(this).attr('data-title');
      var link = $(this).attr('data-url');
      console.log('Marker es: ' + marker);
      marker = [name, lat, lng, link];
      console.log('Y ahora es: ' + marker);
      console.log(marker);
    });

    var markers = [marker];
    console.log(markers);
    console.log(markers.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      marker = new L.marker([markers[i][1], markers[i][2]])
        .bindPopup(markers[i][0])
        .addTo(map);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you are echo-ing the custom field values.
Example: `data-lat="<?php echo get_field('lat'); ?>"` and `data-lat="<?php echo get_field('lon'); ?>"`

Comment: Are the 'lat' and 'lon' values displayed inside the loop as expected?

Comment: Okay, sorry, I misunderstood your problem. So you are getting only one marker on the map. This is because you create the div.marker outside of the loop. You need to loop thru the posts and generate multiple div.marker elements with the custom lat - long values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the div.marker into the loop to display multiple markers with the custom lat-long values.

```
<?php while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ?>
  <div class="marker" 
    data-lat="<?php echo get_field( 'lat' ) ?>" 
    data-lng="<?php echo get_field( 'lon' ); ?>"
    data-title="<?php echo get_field( 'subtitle' )  ?>" 
    data-url="<?php echo 'link'; ?>"
    data-category="<?php echo 'category'; ?>" >
  </div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Also, I would modify your javascript so it will look like this:

```
var markers = [];

$.each($('.marker'), function () {
    var marker = [];
    var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat');
    var lng = $(this).attr('data-lng');
    var name = $(this).attr('data-title');
    var link = $(this).attr('data-url');
    console.log('Marker es: ' + marker);
    marker = [name, lat, lng, link];
    console.log('Y ahora es: ' + marker);
    console.log(marker);
    markers.push( marker );
});


console.log(markers);
console.log(markers.length);
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    marker = new L.marker([markers[i][1], markers[i][2]])
    .bindPopup(markers[i][0])
    .addTo(map);
}
```